# Stripe 1.9.1 error in Magento 2.3.5-p1 - Authentication required

Tags: magento2, api, paypal, stripe

We recently installed the Stripe module but in checkout nothing happens when placing an order, the only thing we can see is in network and console this

```
{"message":"Authentication Required: pi_XXXX_secret_XXXXX"}
```

And in console this

```
POST https://siteurl.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/XXXXX/payment-information 400
```

What can cause this issue? Any help?
Idk if it's related, but Paypal does not work too but I can't see any error so idk if it's the same and all works fone in a test environment both Stripe and Paypal. But in a live nothing works, I tried to disable Cloudflare and all stayed the same so it's not from it I guess.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is related to the 3D Secure authentication of the module, if you have a OneStepCheckout module installed, you might need some integration work. You can reach out to magento@stripe.com for details on how to integrate with your OSC module or checkout customizations.

Comment: I checked real quick 3D Secure in module and I was testing with a card that needed it but it wasn't active, thanks!